# Baba Sali and his Torah chiddushim

Tags: jewish-books, rabbis, acharonim

I can not find any Torah writings from the Baba Sali. Does anybody know where I can find his Torah?

Comment: do you know that he wrote any?

Comment: You can check the sefer Yirsrael Sabba

Answer (score 3):

One Sefer that he wrote is called [Ahavas Yisroel](http://mysefer.com/__p-830.aspx) which lists 127 Mitzvos whose foundation is in the version "love your friend as yourself." I have heard of references to other things being printed, but I haven't found a title other than this one, and as far as I can tell they are all printed posthumously for the first time.

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex, worked for me. I updated it to where it now redirects you to. Unless you meant that it doesn't work in the sense that the book is out of stock ...

Comment: When I clicked it yesterday it led to one of those "page not found" kind of things. It's working now.